# Approval Workflow Cannot be Completed

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have created a workflow using the OOTB Approval workflow template in SP 2010. When I run the workflow, it sends a task to Outlook with the "Open this task" button. When I click on Approve, Reject or Change, it pops up an error message that says "This task could not be updated at this time". I opened the task form in InfoPath and noticed that buttons on the approve form all have rules set up to submit data with data connection of "Approved", "Reject" and "ChangeRequest".

I wonder if the data connection in InfoPath is what's causing the problem? Does anyone have any solution for SP 2010?

Comment: Have you got all of the SharePoint updates on your server? I recall a while back we had an issue with the outlook emails and I believe there was a patch that fixed it. It was similar to, but not identical to your problem.

Comment: Hi Robert, the SP is running with the latest updates. The problem exist not only in Outlook but also in Word. In Word, it will prompt that there is a workflow task. And I get the same error message in Word when I click Approve. I believe it is related to InfoPath because the form button action is from Infopath. Am I right?